# R converting data table to integer vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have some code which, when I run it on one machine, gives me a new data table (segData) with a subset of columns from the original data table (data) as specified within the c(), which is the output I want, but when I run it on a different machine (the one I am currently using), it makes segData an integer vector instead, with the values from inside the c(). It feels like whatever has gone wrong, it's going to be something very obvious as the problem and code are both seemingly trivial. Here is my code:

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("segData2.csv")
segData <- data[, c(3:7, 9:15)]
```

Am I going mad here?

Comment: It's a data.table version thing, probably. Try `data[, c(3:7, 9:15), with=FALSE]` or upgrading.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did wonder if it was some kind of version issue.

Comment: Ok cool. Closing the question against a couple related questions that have answers with more details.